# Using FBFriendPickerViewController to send messages to users in the list in IOS

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I used FriendPickerSample app which came with the Facebook IOS SDK to display a list of my user's Facebook friends. I get an array of FBGraphUser back and can access the id, first_name, last_name, link and address properties.

Now I want to send these users a message inviting them to download our app. What is the next step? Should I not be using FBFriendPickerViewController? If not then what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the friend picker to select friends to send the requests to.

Have a look at the RPS sample that ships with the SDK. If you go into the "See Friends" option (by clicking on the Facebook icon), it allows you to select a friend, and if you click on the invite button at the bottom, it will send an invite request to that user.

Comment: The sample you mention calls [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession] to send the requests. The last parameter of this call is a FBFrictionlessRecipientCache object that is supposed to have 'frictionless' user ids in the recipientIDs property. However in my app and in the sample app there are no ids in this field and nothing gets sent even after selecting users. Any idea how to get frictionless users into a FBFrictionLessRecipientCache object?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is sent? App requests usually go to App Center in Facebook.

Comment: Yes it was actually sent just couldn't find it on facebook. You led me to the right place but I was doing it all wrong. Basically anyone trying to send an invite should user the FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession and not mess with the FBFriendPickerViewController as it gives you a bunch of data you can't use to send an invite. Thanks for your help.